# Laravel artisan migrate connection error

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

I am trying to create a users table using a migration and vagrant box. When I use `artisan migrate` I get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting                                                         
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432? (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = public and tab
  le_name = migrations)

  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Which file do I need to change to setup my connection and what details do I need to use?

Here is my database config:

```
    'pgsql' => [
        'driver' => 'pgsql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'homestead'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'secret'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
        'schema' => 'public',
        'sslmode' => 'prefer',
    ],
```

my .env file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead 
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

I have the dll's uncommented in my `php.ini`, and its pointing to the correct extentions directory:

```
;extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
extension=php_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_shmop.dll
```

When I try and use vagrant shh I get the error:

```
vagrant@homestead:~$ php artisan migrate
Could not open input file: artisan
vagrant@homestead:~$
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you made sure that postgres is actually running? Make sure you can connect to postgres from cli before you try configuring laravel.

Comment: my cli says `The term 'psql' is not recognized` when I open a cmd propmt in my local homestead

Comment: Which confuses me, I thought vagrant homestead came with psql?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue it solved when I added 54320 as A PORT 
just you add 0 to your port it will work.

Answer (score -2):

It's just mean that your MySQL server isn't run or run on different ip-address or port.

Comment: Not MySQL, pgsql, both are different